# Ember.js Undefined retrieving property of a model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have got this model, where site is an array of sites:

```
App.Topology = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
site: DS.attr()
});
```

And I am trying to retrieve this array in a computed property:

```
return this.filterBy('name', this.get('selectedName')).get('site');
```

The filterBy functiion returns correcty:

```
<App.Topology:ember411:1>
```

But with the get('site') it´s undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure filterBy doesn't return an array? so something like `[<App.Topology:ember411:1>]`

Because that's what it's supposed to do, see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filterBy. If it does return an array you can use the firstObject property:

```
return this.filterBy('name', this.get('selectedName')).get('firstObject').get('site');
```